# How to write an echo inside an echoed html link

Tags: php, html, if-statement, echo

Ok so im trying to create a navigation link that can take a user to there profile page. I made a function "find_user_by_id($user_id)" to use for...well...locating the user via there id. All I need is to figure out how to have it where if the user is currently ON there profile page, it shows a "logout" link where the "profile" link would normally be placed. The only problem is, I don't know how to *Echo* `urlencode($user["id"])`inside an already echoed `<a href>`tag. The code below might help you understand a bit more:

```
if ($accessPage =='profile') {
        echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($user["id"]); ?>\">Profile</a>";
    }
```

Comment: Inside an echo statement, there is no need to write again echo.

Comment: Keep your question *consistent*! "Wait what about a function" is not a question that makes any sort of sense. This isn't an ongoing conversation, the question has got to be standalone for the answers to make sense.

Comment: If you want to ask **new question** ask it again as **new question** Don't **edit question** for **new issue**

Answer (score 5):

You just need concatenation.

```
if ($accessPage == 'profile') {
    echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=" .
         urlencode($user["id"]) .
         " \">Profile</a>";
}
```

Comment: What about in redirects or any function for that matter........
[ redirect_to('profile.php?id=\'.urlencode($user["id"]).\'');

Comment: Is javascript, .. so you have to write this: `redirect_to('profile.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($admin["id"]); ?>');`

Comment: go to the bottom of this question page...I put a function there

Comment: edit the question, do not add answers

Answer (score 5):

You dont need another echo, just join strings using . operator

```
echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=". urlencode($user["id"]) . "\">Profile</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do by many ways.
Try this

```
if ($accessPage =='profile') {
        echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='profile.php?id=".urlencode($user["id"])."'>Profile</a>";
    }
```

OR

```
if ($accessPage == 'profile') {
    echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=" .urlencode($user["id"]) ." \">Profile</a>";
}
```

OR

```
<?php if ($accessPage =='profile') { ?>
     <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
     <a href='profile.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($user["id"]) ?>'>Profile</a>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can echo it like this, for example:

`echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=" . urlencode($user["id"]) . "\">Profile</a>";`

I also suggest to use ' instead of " so you don't need to use those backslashes

`echo '<a href="profile.php?id=' . urlencode($user["id"]) . '">Profile</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($accessPage =='profile'){
    echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>";
} else {
    echo '<a href="profile.php?id="'.urlencode($user['id']).'>Profile</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-echo it if it's a function that already returns a `string` type of variable.

This should do:

```
echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=".urlencode($user["id"]).">Profile</a>";
```

To be extra sure though you can get that call result into a variable and cast it to `string` type and replace it in between the two concatenation dots.